# Using sed to mass rename files

Tags: bash, shell, sed, file-rename

**Objective**

Change these filenames:

- F00001-0708-RG-biasliuyda
- F00001-0708-CS-akgdlaul
- F00001-0708-VF-hioulgigl

to these filenames:

- F0001-0708-RG-biasliuyda
- F0001-0708-CS-akgdlaul
- F0001-0708-VF-hioulgigl

**Shell Code**

To test:

```
ls F00001-0708-*|sed 's/\(.\).\(.*\)/mv & \1\2/'
```

To perform:

```
ls F00001-0708-*|sed 's/\(.\).\(.*\)/mv & \1\2/' | sh
```

**My Question**

I don't understand the sed code.  I understand what the substitution
command

```
$ sed 's/something/mv'
```

means.  And I understand regular expressions somewhat.  But I don't
understand what's happening here:

```
\(.\).\(.*\)
```

or here:

```
& \1\2/
```

The former, to me, just looks like it means: "a single character,
followed by a single character, followed by any length sequence of a
single character"--but surely there's more to it than that.  As far as
the latter part:

```
& \1\2/
```

I have no idea.

Comment: See also:  [Changing file extensions with sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44620236/changing-file-extensions-with-sed/44620449#44620449)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

First, I should say that the easiest way to do this is to use the
prename or rename commands.

On Ubuntu, OSX (Homebrew package `rename`, MacPorts package `p5-file-rename`), or other systems with perl rename (prename):

```
rename s/0000/000/ F0000*
```

or on systems with rename from util-linux-ng, such as RHEL:

```
rename 0000 000 F0000*
```

That's a lot more understandable than the equivalent sed command.

But as for understanding the sed command, the sed manpage is helpful. If
you run man sed and search for & (using the / command to search),
you'll find it's a special character in s/foo/bar/ replacements.

```
  s/regexp/replacement/
         Attempt  to match regexp against the pattern space.  If success‐
         ful,  replace  that  portion  matched  with  replacement.    The
         replacement may contain the special character & to refer to that
         portion of the pattern space  which  matched,  and  the  special
         escapes  \1  through  \9  to refer to the corresponding matching
         sub-expressions in the regexp.
```

Therefore, `\(.\)` matches the first character, which can be referenced by `\1`.
Then `.` matches the next character, which is always 0.
Then `\(.*\)` matches the rest of the filename, which can be referenced by `\2`.

The replacement string puts it all together using `&` (the original
filename) and `\1\2` which is every part of the filename except the 2nd
character, which was a 0.

This is a pretty cryptic way to do this, IMHO.  If for
some reason the rename command was not available and you wanted to use
sed to do the rename (or perhaps you were doing something too complex
for rename?), being more explicit in your regex would make it much
more readable.  Perhaps something like:

```
ls F00001-0708-*|sed 's/F0000\(.*\)/mv & F000\1/' | sh
```

Being able to see what's actually changing in the
s/search/replacement/ makes it much more readable. Also it won't keep
sucking characters out of your filename if you accidentally run it
twice or something.

Comment: on my RHEL server, the rename syntax would be "rename 0000 000 F0000*"

Comment: On my ArchLinux installation, `s///` should be `-s///`, or else it complains about "too many arguments".

Comment: It is most likely that `rename` is itself a *"renamed"* link.  ie `rename` has been *"renamed"* from `prename`.. eg, in Ubuntu: `readlink -f $(which rename)` outputs `/usr/bin/prename` ... The `rename` mentioned by *David* is a different program entirely.

Comment: Good point, Peter. I've updated the answer to address both rename utilities.

Comment: To debug this, remove the pipe into sh at the end. The commands will echo out to the screen.

Comment: Why the hell is this symlinked to rename in Ubuntu? I tried to use rename expecting the same syntax in Arch and got a rude surprise. This is something that can break shell scripts easily.

Comment: Are you sure it's a good advice to give to pipe random data through `sh`? this is potentially dangerous as arbitrary code can be executed (you're treating data as code).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf That's a good thing to be wary of. I made the assumption here that the filenames are pretty basic and not malicious. Beware when running this without knowing that the filenames are safe, not containing characters that are meaningful to the shell.

Comment: The rename tool even allows for sub-expression matches using (man rename) the `-e` switch. This way you can even move a matched pattern around within the string easily. as in `rename -e 's/.CR2.~([1-9])~/-shot-on-different-sdcard\1.CR2/' IMG_*`

Comment: On Ubuntu, `rename` prefers `$1` over `\1` for matched pattern references.

Comment: on CentOS/RHEL, I believe if you want to replace a string with an empty string, `""` is needed.

Comment: Thanks a ton. working on an old server with no rename and no install permission. saved me a headache.

Answer (score 57):

you've had your sed explanation, now you can use just the shell, no need external commands

```
for file in F0000*
do
    echo mv "$file" "${file/#F0000/F000}"
    # ${file/#F0000/F000} means replace the pattern that starts at beginning of string
done
```

Comment: Nice but you can't do references with parentheses.

Comment: I was confused until I realised this doesn't run the rename command, it only lists it. To actually run the rename, just replace `echo` with `eval`

Comment: Or remove echo. In current Mac zsh, you can actually remove the do/done too.

```for file in F0000*```
```mv $file ${file/0000/000}```

Answer (score 49):

I wrote a small post with examples on batch renaming using `sed` couple of years ago:

http://www.guyrutenberg.com/2009/01/12/batch-renaming-using-sed/

For example:

```
for i in *; do
  mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed "s/regex/replace_text/"`";
done
```

If the regex contains groups (e.g. `\(subregex\`) then you can use them in the replacement text as `\1\`,`\2` etc.

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.

Comment: not that efficient, but gets the work done for couple hundred files. Upvoted.

Answer (score 25):

The easiest way would be:

```
for i in F00001*; do mv "$i" "${i/F00001/F0001}"; done
```

or, portably,

```
for i in F00001*; do mv "$i" "F0001${i#F00001}"; done
```

This replaces the `F00001` prefix in the filenames with `F0001`.
credits to mahesh here: http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/150

Comment: You should properly quote the variable interpolations; `mv "$i" "${i/F00001/F0001}"`. But +1

Answer (score 9):

Using perl rename (a *must have* in the toolbox):

```
rename -n 's/0000/000/' F0000*
```

Remove `-n` switch when the output looks good to rename for real.

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

The rename command that is part of the `util-linux` package, won't.

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ rename
```

and you see `perlexpr`, then this seems to be the right tool.

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo apt install rename
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /usr/bin/file-rename
```

---

For archlinux:

```
pacman -S perl-rename
```

---

For RedHat-family distros:

```
yum install prename
```

The 'prename' package is in the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository.

---

For Gentoo:

```
emerge dev-perl/rename
```

---

For *BSD:

```
pkg install gprename
```

or `p5-File-Rename`

---

For Mac users:

```
brew install rename
```

---

If you don't have this command with another distro, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL):

```
cpan -i File::Rename
```

Old standalone version can be found [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sputnick-dev/perl-rename/master/rename)

---

[man rename](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/rename/file-rename.1p.en.html)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: after running some of the for loop versions, i was *absolutely stunned* how fast rename regex was. i was having a bunch of trouble with multibyte chars and spaces in names. definitely not worth the time to fool with all the escaping necessary to genereate `mv` statements. `rename` for the win.

Answer (score 8):

The `sed` command

```
s/\(.\).\(.*\)/mv & \1\2/
```

means to replace:

```
\(.\).\(.*\)
```

with:

```
mv & \1\2
```

just like a regular `sed` command. However, the parentheses, `&` and `\n` markers change it a little.

The search string matches (and remembers as pattern 1) the single character at the start, followed by a single character, follwed by the rest of the string (remembered as pattern 2).

In the replacement string, you can refer to these matched patterns to use them as part of the replacement. You can also refer to the whole matched portion as `&`.

So what that `sed` command is doing is creating a `mv` command based on the original file (for the source) and character 1 and 3 onwards, effectively removing character 2 (for the destination). It will give you a series of lines along the following format:

```
mv F00001-0708-RG-biasliuyda F0001-0708-RG-biasliuyda
mv abcdef acdef
```

and so on.

Comment: This was a good explanation, but it could be useful to point out how you use the sed command with other commands to actually rename the files. For example: `ls | sed "s/\(.\).\(.*\)/mv & \1\2/" | bash`

Comment: @jcarballo: it is dangerous to parse `ls`, pipe through `sed` and _then pipe through a shell!_ it's subject to arbitrary code execution with forged filenames. The problem is that data should be treated as data, and here it's typically serialized into code without any precautions whatsoever. I wish paxdiablo could delete this answer as it really doesn't show good practice. (I stumbled on this question because a beginner randomly piped `| sh` after a command that didn't work and after seeing this question and the answers thought it would work better—I'm horrified!) `:)`.

Answer (score 3):

The backslash-paren stuff means, "while matching the pattern, hold on to the stuff that matches in here."  Later, on the replacement text side, you can get those remembered fragments back with "\1" (first parenthesized block), "\2" (second block), and so on.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in *; do mv $i $(echo $i|sed 's/AAA/BBB/'); done
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please consider adding explanation of your code. It will help other users in understanding it.

Comment: This answer is good but it's a near duplicate answer of a highly upvoted answer above.

Comment: As written, this code may fail for filenames containing spaces. To fix the problem, one should add quotes `"` around the `$(echo ...)`.

Answer (score 1):

If all you're really doing is removing the second character, regardless of what it is, you can do this:

```
s/.//2
```

but your command is building a `mv` command and piping it to the shell for execution.

This is no more readable than your version:

```
find -type f | sed -n 'h;s/.//4;x;s/^/mv /;G;s/\n/ /g;p' | sh
```

The fourth character is removed because `find` is prepending each filename with "./".

Comment: I wish you could delete this answer. While it was maybe good in the very specific case of the OP, there are lots of people seeing answers like this and don't understand it, and randomly pipe `| sh` after a command that doesn't work, in the hope that it'll work better. It's horrifying! (and besides, that's not good practice). I hope you'll understand!

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

```
for file in *.[Jj][Pp][Gg] ;do 
    echo mv -vi \"$file\" `jhead $file|
                           grep Date|
                           cut -b 16-|
                           sed -e 's/:/-/g' -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/$/.jpg/g'` ;
done
```

Then if that looks ok, add `| sh` to the end. So:

```
for file in *.[Jj][Pp][Gg] ;do 
    echo mv -vi \"$file\" `jhead $file|
                           grep Date|
                           cut -b 16-|
                           sed -e 's/:/-/g' -e 's/ /_/g' -e 's/$/.jpg/g'` ;
done | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

The parentheses capture particular strings for use by the backslashed numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ls F00001-0708-*|sed 's|^F0000\(.*\)|mv & F000\1|' | bash
```

Comment: Horrible! subject to arbitrary code execution (maybe not in the specific context of the question, but there are lots of people seeing answers like this and try to randomly type something that look like it, and it's scaring dangerous!). I wish you could delete this answer (besides, you have another good one on here, that I upvoted).

Answer (score 0):

Some examples that work for me:

```sh
$ tree -L 1 -F .
.
├── A.Show.2020.1400MB.txt
└── Some Show S01E01 the Loreming.txt

0 directories, 2 files

## remove "1400MB" (I: ignore case) ...

$ for f in *; do mv 2>/dev/null -v "$f" "`echo $f | sed -r 's/.[0-9]{1,}mb//I'`"; done;
renamed 'A.Show.2020.1400MB.txt' -> 'A.Show.2020.txt'

## change "S01E01 the" to "S01E01 The"
## \U& : change (here: regex-selected) text to uppercase;
##       note also: no need here for `\1` in that regex expression

$ for f in *; do mv 2>/dev/null "$f" "`echo $f | sed -r "s/([0-9] [a-z])/\U&/"`"; done

$ tree -L 1 -F .
.
├── A.Show.2020.txt
└── Some Show S01E01 The Loreming.txt

0 directories, 2 files
$
```

- `2>/dev/null` suppresses extraneous output (warnings ...)
- reference [this thread]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2372808/1904943
- change case: https://www.networkworld.com/article/3529409/converting-between-uppercase-and-lowercase-on-the-linux-command-line.html