# Rename files using cmd and allow duplicates file name

Tags: batch-file, cmd, duplicates, rename

I have my batch file which consists of the following command.

```
REN "H:\April2012\A04\mr_sudheendra_holla_vaderhobli.pdf.1335780379203.ver1" "mr_sudheendra_holla_vaderhobli.pdf"
```

But if duplicate files exist, the command will not execute. I would like my command to rename the file name to `*(1).pdf` and `*(2).pdf` etc. if there are duplicates. How can I do that?

Comment: Please don't crosspost [Rename files using cmd and allow duplicates file name](https://superuser.com/q/849881)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows batch file to copy and keep duplicates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248393/windows-batch-file-to-copy-and-keep-duplicates)

Comment: @DavidPostill - Definitely not a duplicate. REN is not the same as COPY, plus the technique used in the one and only answer would not work for this problem.

Comment: @dbenham Not an exact duplicate, but rename is copy followed by delete ... so the dup answer is a starting point ...

Comment: @DavidPostill - No, the "dup" answer is not a starting point because it assumes the target folder starts out empty. There could easily be name collisions if applied to rename.

Comment: It's actually more a question of logic, than a question of coding. Obviously, if you want to switch 2 names, and both "exist" at all time, you can only solve that by giving one a temporary name.

Answer (score 2):

**renDup.bat**

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
ren %1 %2 2>nul && echo %1 --^> "%~n2(%max%)%~x2"|| call :renDup %1 %2
exit /b

:renDup
set max=0
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b "%~dp1%~n2(*)%~x2" 2^>nul ^| findstr /ri "([1-9][0-9]*)\%~x2$"'
) do call :getMax "%%~nF"
set /a max+=1
ren %1 "%~n2(%max%)%~x2" && echo %1 --^> "%~n2(%max%)%~x2"
exit /b

:getMax
set "name=%~1"
set "name=%name:~0,-1%"
for %%N in ("%name:(=.%") do set num=%%~xN
set /a num=%num:~1%
if %num% gtr %max% set "max=%num%"
exit /b
```

**usage:**

```
renDup "H:\April2012\A04\mr_sudheendra_holla_vaderhobli.pdf.1335780379203.ver1" "mr_sudheendra_holla_vaderhobli.pdf"
```

Comment: This works great, however, I prefer `filename_012` over `filename(12)` and am unable to adjust your script accordingly. I think I figuered everything out but this: `("%name:(=.%")`. Could you please help me? :)