# How to add suffix to duplicate filenames output by ffmpeg in Windows batch file?

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, batch-rename

I have written a script in Sony Vegas Pro that outputs an edit list of video files (E:\editlist.txt) of the following form, where the 2nd item is the start timecode and the 3rd item is the length:

```
E:\folder\file1a.mp4 16.8835333 17.5175
E:\folder\file2a.mp4 6.0393666 12.1454666
E:\folder\file3a.mp4 0 3.5368667
E:\folder\file3a.mp4 5.1344667 9.3033
E:\folder\file3a.mp4 12.1224623 19.483756
```

I have also cobbled together a Windows batch script that uses ffmpeg to trim those files and re-wrap them in a .mov container.

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%F in (E:\editlist.txt) do ffmpeg.exe -ss "%%G" -i "%%F" -c copy -t "%%H" "%%~dF%%~pF%%~nF.mov"
```

However because some files originate from the same source file (in this case, file3a.mp4), the trimmed files have duplicate names.

I would like to create a script that detects duplicates and adds an incremental single-digit suffix to the output file names, before the file extension. In this case the 5 output files should be file1a.mov, file2a.mov, file3a.mov, file3a1.mov and file3a2.mov.

I have had a go but I have no experience of writing Windows batch files, so the following effort fails and is probably very wrong, but hopefully it shows what I am trying to achieve (it was loosely based on [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248393/windows-batch-file-to-copy-and-keep-duplicates)):

```
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%F in (E:\editlist.txt)
    set counter=0
    if exist "%%~dF%%~pF%%~nF.mov" (
    set counter=%counter%+1
    do ffmpeg.exe -ss "%%G" -i "%%F" -c copy -t "%%H" "%%~dF%%~pF%%~nF%counter%.mov"
) else do ffmpeg.exe -ss "%%G" -i "%%F" -c copy -t "%%H" "%%~dF%%~pF%%~nF.mov"
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me get this working. Thanks!

Comment: You missed `do (` in the first line of your second attempt

Comment: Thank you Paul. If I simply add `do (` to the end of the first line it doesn't work. I can see that leaves me with an extra `(` at the end of the 3rd line, but if I delete that then it still doesn't work. Bear in mind that the counter needs to be reset to 0 for each "set" of duplicates.

Comment: if you add `do (` you have to enclose with `)` in the right place. Also `else do` is incorrect too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the list file is sorted and the file names don't contain `!`, use [set /a](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) for calculations and enable the [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set prevfile=
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%F in (E:\editlist.txt) do (
    if "%%F"=="!prevfile!" (
        if "!counter!"=="" (set counter=1) else (set /a counter+=1)
    ) else (
        set counter=
        set "prevfile=%%F"
    )
    ffmpeg -ss "%%G" -i "%%F" -c copy -t "%%H" "%%~dpnF!counter!.mov"
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

It just a syntax correction of your second attempt. Don't take it as answer.

```dos
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%F in (E:\editlist.txt) do (
    set counter=0
    if exist "%%~dF%%~pF%%~nF.mov" (
        set counter=%counter%+1
        ffmpeg.exe -ss "%%G" -i "%%F" -c copy -t "%%H" "%%~dF%%~pF%%~nF%counter%.mov"
    ) else (
        ffmpeg.exe -ss "%%G" -i "%%F" -c copy -t "%%H" "%%~dF%%~pF%%~nF.mov"
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is your original method, with a couple details fixed:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims= " %%F in (E:\editlist.txt) do (
    if exist "%%~dF%%~pF%%~nF.mov" (
        set /A counter=counter+1
    ) else (
        set "counter="
    )
    ffmpeg.exe -ss "%%G" -i "%%F" -c copy -t "%%H" "%%~dF%%~pF%%~nF!counter!.mov"
)
```

When a variable is not defined, `set /A` command insert a zero in its place.