# How to use sed to change file extensions?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I have to do a sed line (also using pipes in Linux) to change a file extension, so I can do some kind of `mv *.1stextension *.2ndextension` like `mv *.txt *.c`. The thing is that I can't use batch or a for loop, so I have to do it all with pipes and sed command.

Comment: Why you can't use loop ? You should make it clear ! Are you doing this as a part of a homework ?

Comment: of course i am, i didn't mentioned but i think it's pretty known because of teh restrictions

Answer (score 12):

you can use string manipulation

```
filename="file.ext1"
mv "${filename}" "${filename/%ext1/ext2}"
```

Or if your system support, you can use `rename`.

**Update**

you can also do something like this

```
mv ${filename}{ext1,ext2}
```

which is called brace expansion

Comment: I wonder if we are allowed to user `rename` ...it is available in most Linux system

Comment: Thanks, but i cant use any batch or script sentence, I just can use my command line, sed and pipes

Comment: what exactly your input? what kind of output do you expect? if only `sed` allowed I don't think you can rename a file.

Comment: @user2113403: `for filename in *.1stextension; do mv "${filename}" "${filename/%1stextension/2ndextension}"; done` will do for a bunch of files. No need for `sed`.

Comment: POSIX: `${filename%.ext1}.ext2`

Answer (score 5):

sed is for manipulating the contents of files, not the filename itself. My suggestion:

```
rename 's/\.ext/\.newext/' ./*.ext
```

Or, there's this [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372719/using-sed-to-mass-rename-files) which should help.

Comment: I had to substitute .c with .o in a Makefile. This solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This may work:

```
find . -name "*.txt" | 
sed -e 's|./||g' | 
awk '{print "mv",$1, $1"c"}' | 
sed -e "s|\.txtc|\.c|g" > table;
chmod u+x table;
./table
```

I don't know why you can't use a loop. It makes life much easier :

```
newex="c";  # Give your new extension
for file in *.*;  # You can replace with *.txt instead of *.*
do 
 ex="${file##*.}";    # This retrieves the file extension
 ne=$(echo "$file" | sed -e "s|$ex|$newex|g"); # Replaces current with the new one
 echo "$ex";echo "$ne";
 mv "$file" "$ne";
done
```

Comment: I'm supposed not to use any loop or sentence, just pipes, comand line and sed

Answer (score 3):

You can use `find` to find all of the files and then pipe that into a `while read` loop:

```
$ find . -name "*.ext1" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
do
   mv $file "${file%.*}.ext2"
done
```

The `${file%.*}` is the *small right pattern filter*. The `%` marks the pattern to remove from the right side (matching the smallest glob pattern possible), The `.*` is the pattern (the last `.` followed by the characters after the `.`).

The `-print0` will separate file names with the `NUL` character instead of `\n`. The `-d $'\0'` will read in file names separated by the `NUL` character. This way, file names with spaces, tabs, `\n`, or other wacky characters will be processed correctly.

Comment: How this is not a loop ? OP doesn't want any loop !

Comment: It's a pipe. As the OP said "_so i have to do it all with **pipes** and sed command_". I'm not sure what the issue the OP was having with `for`, but `for` can be troublesome because of the way it parses the parameters for the loop. Unfortunately, the OP didn't provide much information what they are doing. With more info, I could give a better answer.

Comment: Agree with you that OP doesn't provide enough information, why not loop !

Answer (score 2):

You may try following options

**Option 1** `find` along with `rename`

```
find . -type f -name "*.ext1" -exec rename -f 's/\.ext1$/ext2/' {} \;
```

**Option 2** `find` along with `mv`

```
find . -type f -name "*.ext1" -exec sh -c 'mv -f $0 ${0%.ext1}.ext2' {} \;
```

*Note: It is observed that `rename` doesn't work for many terminals*

Comment: @iamauser try using option 2 `mv` if `rename` is not working. Even I am not sure why `rename` doesn't work for many terminals. For me it works in `ubuntu` but not in `RHEL`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution only with sed and sh

```
printf "%s\n" *.ext1 | 
sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g"';s/\(.*\)'ext1'/mv '\''\1'ext1\'' '\''\1'ext2\''/g' | 
sh
```

for better performance: only one process created

```
perl -le '($e,$f)=@ARGV;map{$o=$_;s/$e$/$f/;rename$o,$_}<*.$e>' ext2 ext3
```

Answer (score 0):

well this should work

```
mv $file $(echo $file | sed -E -e 's/.xml.bak.*/.xml/g' | sed -E -e 's/.\///g')
```

output

```
abc.xml.bak.foobar -> abc.xml
```