# Changing file extensions with sed

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed

If the arguments are files, I want to change their extensions to `.file`.

That's what I got:

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    if [ -f $1 ]
    then
       sed -i -e "s/\(.*\)\(\.\)\(.*\)/\1\2file" $1

    fi
    shift
done
```

The script is running, but it doesn't do anything. Another problem is that file hasn't any extension, my sed command will not work, right? Please help.

Comment: If anything, sed is meant to change the contents of files, not their names. You can use it for the latter, but it's hardly the best tool for it. Your sed command doesn't say what sed should even act on, I supposed your script just hangs on that line, right?

Comment: yes,i forgot a $1 after the sed command when i asked the question. but it is not working anyway.

Comment: Yes, because that command changes the *contents* of the files, not their names.

Comment: Also, i tried a  : $1 mv $1.file but it gives me file.txt.file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sed is for manipulating the contents of files, not the filename itself.

Option 1, taken from [this answer by John Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165105/3266847):

> ```
> filename="file.ext1"
> mv "${filename}" "${filename/%ext1/ext2}"
> ```

Option 2, taken from [this answer by chooban](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165876/3266847):

> ```
> rename 's/\.ext/\.newext/' ./*.ext
> ```

Option 3, taken from [this answer by David W.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19165370/3266847):

> ```
> $ find . -name "*.ext1" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
> do
>    mv $file "${file%.*}.ext2"
> done
> ```

and more is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19164976/how-to-use-sed-to-change-file-extensions).

UPDATE : (in comment asked what % and {} doing?)

"${variable}othter_chars" > if you want expand a variable in string you can use it. and `%.*` in `{}` means take the value of variable strip off the pattern `.*` from the tail of the value for example if your variable be `filename.txt` "${variable%.*} return just `filename`.

Comment: The extension of the file is not given. It can be .txt or .file or anything. I want the script to not care about that.

Comment: that's not so big deal man you can in option 3 relpace `"*.ext1"` with `"*.*"` to get any filename with any extention.

Comment: Ty,man. It's working. Can you tell me,please what %  and {} doing? it's the first time when i`m using them.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect more clearly that all solutions are taken from existing answers. If you feel an existing answer is the exact solution to a new question, you should not answer the new question, but mark it as a duplicate of the old one.

Comment: @Benjamin Thanks and sorry for i'm not mentioned orginal answer.

Comment: @EduardAdrian i update the answer for your question i hope it help you.

Answer (score 1):

Using a shell function to wrap a `sed` *evaluate* (`e`) command:

```
mvext () 
{ 
    ext="$1";
    while shift && [ "$1" ]; do
        sed 's/.*/mv -iv "&" "&/
             s/\(.*\)\.[^.]*$/\1/
             s/.*/&\.'"${ext}"'"/e' <<< "$1";
    done
}
```

Tests, given files *bah* and *boo*, and the extension should be *.file*, which is then changed to *.buzz*:

```
 mvext file bah boo
 mvext buzz b*.file
```

Output:

```
'bah' -> 'bah.file'
'boo' -> 'boo.file'
'bah.file' -> 'bah.buzz'
'boo.file' -> 'boo.buzz'
```

---

How it works:

1. The first arg is the file extension, which is stored in *$ext*.
2. The `while` loop parses each file name separately, since a name might include escaped spaces and whatnot.  If the filenames were *certain* to have not such escaped spaces, the `while` loop could probably be avoided.
3. `sed` reads standard input, provided by a `bash` *here string* `<<< "$1"`.
4. The `sed` code changes each name *foo.bar* (or even just plain *foo*) to the string "*mv -iv foo.bar
   foo.file*" then runs that string with the `e`*valuate* command.  The `-iv` options show what's been moved and prompts if an existing file might be overwritten.