# Rename files by reordering pattern in bash

Tags: bash, rename

I have a pdf files in the format:

```
Author-YYYY-rest_of_text_seperated_by_underscores.pdf
John-2010-some_file.pdf
Smith-2009-some_other_file.pdf
```

I need to rename the files so that the year is first e.g.

```
YYYY-Author-rest_of_text_seperated_by_underscores.pdf
2010-John-some_file.pdf
2009-Smith-some_other_file.pdf
```

So that would mean moving the 'YYYY-' element to the start.

I do not have unix 'Rename' and must rely on sed, awk etc.I happy to rename inplace.

I have been trying to adapt this answer not having much luck. [Using sed to mass rename files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372719/using-sed-to-mass-rename-files)

Comment: Please don't tag questions with tools that aren't actually at the center of the question itself. `awk` and `sed` may be useful in an answer, but they're not what you're actually asking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) for general advice on string manipulation with bash. One of the techniques this goes into is [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), which is heavily used in the below:

```
pat=-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-
for f in *$pat*; do  # expansion not quoted here to expand the glob
  prefix=${f%%$pat*} # strip first instance of the pattern and everything after -> prefix
  suffix=${f#*$pat}  # strip first instance and everything before -> suffix 
  year=${f#"$prefix"}; year=${year%"$suffix"} # find the matched year itself
  mv -- "$f" "${year}-${prefix}-${suffix}"    # ...and move.
done
```

By the way, [BashFAQ #30](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/030) discusses lots of rename mechanisms, among them one using `sed` to run arbitrary transforms.

Comment: Accepted this answer as it worked 1st pass and for explanation in comments :)

Answer (score 3):

Using BASH regex:

```
re='^([^-]+-)([0-9]{4}-)(.*)$'

for f in *.pdf; do
    [[ $f =~ $re ]] &&
    echo mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
done
```

When you're happy with the output remove `echo` command before `mv`.

Comment: recieved an error 'conditional binary operator expected'

Comment: I've tested it in BASH and it worked without any error. Make sure you are using `bash` as well

Comment: @BenP, hmm -- this *should* work. What's your shebang? If you were running your script with `/bin/sh` instead of bash, that would be expected to cause a failure.