# Unix rename command for one character on filename

Tags: linux, unix, aix

I have over 1,000 files that I will like to change one character on the filename, Ex: GM001001, GM001002, GM001003, etc.. to be rename to GX001001, GX001002, GX001003, etc... As you can see the common denominator will be the M to be replace for an X.

Comment: Sorry, voting-to-close because ***"Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more"***.... StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Comment: Some systems have a Perl-based `rename` (occasionally `prename`) command.  You'd write: `rename s/GM/GX/ GM[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` to rename all the files starting with the letters GM and continuing with six digits.  See also [Usiing `sed` to mass rename files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2372719/15168) where the accepted answer advocates for using `rename` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `mv` with [string replace](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to achieve this:

```
for f in $(ls)
do
  mv $f ${f/GM/GX}
done
```

Comment: Note that using `for f in $(ls)` is generally not a good idea.  A better choice would be a glob such as `for f in GM[0-9]*` which will handle spaces etc in the file names correctly (unlike the version using `ls`).  Granted, the names are probably simple enough that it isn't an issue.  The `ls` notation also would list files not starting `GM`.  The `[0-9]` bit is a sop in the direction of ensuring that files names have the right format.  Using `GM[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` would be far more verbose but more reliable for the six-digit numbers shown in thee question.

Comment: Perfect, It worked fine. Thank you!