# changing file extensions using sed command in linux

Tags: linux, sed

I wanted to change all of the files extensions in a folder to .jpg using only sed command.

I tried using

```
sed -i 's/\.*/\.jpg/g' ~/cw/
```

cw is my folder where i have files like:

- cat.jpg
- dog.JPG
- frog.jpeg

etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sed to mass rename files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2372719/using-sed-to-mass-rename-files)

Comment: not really, I wanted to change .jpeg, .JPG and not the names of the files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
sed -n 's/\(^[^.]*\.\)[jJ][pP]e\?[gG]/mv & \1jpg/p' <(find ~/cw/)
```

If the dry run indeed changes the files to the expected extension, then you can then execute the command within the `sed` command

```
sed -n 's/\(^[^.]*\.\)[jJ][pP]e\?[gG]/mv & \1jpg/pe' <(find ~/cw/)
```